# Blank Screen After Ubuntu 12 installation

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

On my dell laptop, running with windows 7, I installed Ubuntu 12. I used it for sometime, then i re-started to switch to windows. First time it got boot up with windows but then it got hanged. I re-started again and then blank screen with blinking cursor came and beep sounds also started to came.

I read in few forums and this seems like a common issue with Ubuntu. I tried using the bootable USB for both windows 7 and Ubuntu but none of these are even getting detected.

Please let me know if any of know the work-around.

Below is configuration" Machine: Dell Studio BIOS: Phoenix OS: Windows 7 Motherboard: Intel

Comment: I have already refereed to many post in this forum but none of them seems to be working in this case.

Comment: My friends tried removing the hard drive from my laptop to check wheter problem is with BIOS or Hard Drive. In the end, we found Hard Drive is not getting detected. Now, my question is why after installing ubuntu this problem came? is it just a co-incidence?